# Initialize a String Array From a string-array resource

Tags: android, arrays

I have the following declared at the top of my class:

```
private String[] mapTypes = new String[]{"Normal", "Satellite", "Satellite with streets", "Terrain"};
```

I also have the following string-array resource defined:

```
<string-array
    name="map_types">
        <item>Normal</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>Satellite with streets</item>
        <item>Terrain</item>
</string-array>
```

I would like to initialize the array from the string-array resource at the top of the class. i.e. do something like the following, when declaring the variable:

```
private String[] mapTypeNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.map_types);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "the class" is something that inherits from `Context`, you are welcome to have the field in the class, but you cannot initialize it until the appropriate lifecycle method (e.g., `onCreate()` in the activity). `getResources()` will not work until then.

If "the class" is something that does not inherit from `Context`, what you want syntactically is not possible by default. And, even if you implement your own `getResources()` method, that in turn eventually needs a `Context`, and you are back to square one.

Comment: That is what I thought. I was just trying to avoid initializing the array every time onCreate() is executed and, at the same time, being a good boy and using the resources

Comment: @ChrisRead: "I was just trying to avoid initializing the array every time onCreate() is executed" -- you wouldn't be saving anything. `onCreate()` is only executed when the activity is created, which will be shortly after it is instantiated. So would your field initializer.